# how to generate method with an out parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

Using System.Reflection, how can I generate a method with an `out` parameter?

I can generate a `ref` using `MakeByRefType` but I can't find anything about any `MakeOutType`...

```
typeBuilder.DefineMethod("myfunc", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() });
```

Comment: You forgot to mention why Interop is involved. Currently your question reads like you want to create `DoSomething(out int myInt)`, whereas you seem to want `DoSomething([Out] int myInt)`.

Answer (score 3):

Thats  because there is no `out int` type. Out is an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), and the keyword `out` is a syntaxic sugar.

You have to specify this parameter attribute at parameter definition :

```
var mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("myfunc", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() });
var paramBuilder = mb.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.Out, "a");
// or: paramBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(OutAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[0]), new object[0]));
```